# how to match two array using foreach

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, compare

> The thing that I want to do is to compare the two arrays, find out if any duplication has been made in the second array versus the first array. Then if there has been any duplication, remove it from the second array so that if they select the same value in both lists that it will only be in the first.
>
> ```
> first array (1,2,3,6,7.9)
> second array (4,5,6,9,10,11)
> ```

```
results would be 
first array (1,2,3,6,7,9)
second array (4,5,10,11)
```

Comment: which programming language are you talking about? in php ?

Comment: YES I AM USING PHP

Comment: do `array_flip` on first & iterate over second array. Check the `isset` method of each value on first array & if found then `unset` the value

Comment: i want to match a latitude of both the array value.

Comment: Yes, that solution will suffice your requirements. you understand the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $first = array (1,2,3,6,7,9);
    $second  = array (4,5,10,11);
    foreach ($second as $k=>$v){
        if(in_array($v, $first)){
            unset($second[$k]);
        }
    }
    $second = array_values($second);
    print_r($second); //Output
```

Comment: how can i match latitude i am using this method

Comment: `$clean1=[];
         $clean2 =[];

         foreach($da as $key=> $value){
        foreach ($response['results'] as $key => $value1){
       if (round($value['geometry']['location']['lat'],5) !== 
       round($value1['geometry']['location']['lat'],5) && 
       !in_array($value1['geometry']['location']['lat'], $clean2)){
       array_push($clean2, $value1);
       array_push($clean1, $value);

      }
    
       }
      }`

Comment: Please provide `$da` and `$response['results']` sample values as well as explain about your desire output in **edit question.**

Comment: foreach($da as $key=> $value) is my databse results                                                               and foreach($response['results'] as $key=>$value1 is google api data             i just want  to output like i have mentioned above in my question

Comment: i want output like this  way                                                                                                 
                                   first array (1,2,3,6,7.9)
                                     second array (4,5,6,9,10,11)
                                         results would be 
                                         first array (1,2,3,6,7,9)
                                          second array (4,5,10,11)

Comment: the thing is i am rounding off google api laitude and my databse data latitude in 4 decimal places and match but it is not working properly